# What is the first things to do when you start a new job?

Tags: professionalism, new-job, england

So In a weeks time I will be leaving my current company and heading to fields a new (kind of, will explain further in)

The company I work for is a client of the company I am moving to, this was set up by my old boss (who moved to the company I am moving to) and my current boss the MD of my current company.

On the first day what is the best way to "Start", I know this is slightly subjective, but is there such a thing as a truly objective question when it comes to employment?

To help make it easier to Answer
I work in England
I will be working in an I.T based support office for a major but small software company.

Comment: "major but small software company" looks interesting :)

Comment: [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)

Comment: See also: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/48276/first-proper-job-making-good-first-impressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't already ask during a possible interview, you could start by asking what they expect you to accomplish in the first 3-6 months. And of course which software is used and which technologies you should get acquainted with to do the job well.